# Plotting two parametric functions in Gnuplot with two command lines separated by a ',\'?

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

When plotting functions of a single variable, I can plot multiple functions with a command of the form

```
plot  x ti "first function",\
      x**2.0 ti "second function"
```

I would like to do the same thing with a parametric plot, but this does not work in the example that I am interested in. I produced a minimal working example for you:

```
K = 360.0/(2.0*pi);
k = 1.0/K;

xe(lambda) =  (-1.0) * ( ((0.0 <= lambda) & (lambda < 180.0)) ? lambda: lambda - 360.0 )*k
ye(phi) = (log(1./cos(phi*k) + tan(phi*k)))

set parametric
set multiplot

PHI(t, d, GHA, omega) =pi/2.-acos(cos(omega) * sin(d)-cos(d) * cos(t) * sin(omega))
LAMBDA(t, d, GHA, omega) = ( lambda = -(atan((-sin(GHA) * (cos(d)* cos(omega)+cos(t) * sin(d) * sin(omega))+cos(GHA) * sin(omega) * sin(t))/(cos(d) * cos(GHA) * cos(omega)+sin(omega)*  (cos(GHA) * cos(t) * sin(d)+sin(GHA)* sin(t)))) + (cos(d)* cos(GHA)* cos(omega) +  sin(omega) * (cos(GHA)* cos(t) * sin(d) + sin(GHA)  *sin(t)) >0.0 ? 0.0 : pi)) , lambda - 2.0*pi*floor(lambda/(2.0*pi)))

lambda_min = 170;
lambda_max = 190;
phi_min = 310;
phi_max = 80;

set xrange [xe(lambda_min):xe(lambda_max)]
set yrange [ye(phi_min):ye(phi_max)]

plot [0.:2.09 ] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)) lt 1 linecolor rgb "red" ti "A" ,\
[2.09:2.*pi] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))  lt 1 linecolor rgb "blue" ti "B"
```

On

> Gnuplot Version 5.4 patchlevel 2 last modified 2021-06-01

this yields the following plot: [image] where the curves "A" and "B" overlap.

However, if I split the plotting command into separate lines by replacing the last two lines with

```
plot [0.:2.09 ] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)) lt 1 linecolor rgb "red" ti "A"
plot [2.09:2.*pi] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))  lt 1 linecolor rgb "blue" ti "B"
```

then I get this plot [image].

I would like to obtain the second graphical result by keeping the first plot command

```
plot [0.:2.09 ] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)) lt 1 linecolor rgb "red" ti "A" ,\
[2.09:2.*pi] xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25)), ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))  lt 1 linecolor rgb "blue" ti "B"
```

and without altering the other elements in the script (even though they may seem useless in the mimimal working example, they are needed for the actual, non-minimal plot which I would like to do).

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me. It uses the special filename `'+'` within the desired parametric ranges, check `help special-filenames` and `help sampling 1D`.

**Code:**

```
### parametric curve
reset session

K = 360.0/(2.0*pi);
k = 1.0/K;

xe(lambda) =  (-1.0) * ( ((0.0 <= lambda) & (lambda < 180.0)) ? lambda: lambda - 360.0 )*k
ye(phi)    = (log(1./cos(phi*k) + tan(phi*k)))

PHI(t, d, GHA, omega)    =  pi/2.-acos(cos(omega) * sin(d)-cos(d) * cos(t) * sin(omega))
LAMBDA(t, d, GHA, omega) = ( lambda = -(atan((-sin(GHA) * (cos(d)* cos(omega)+cos(t) * sin(d) * sin(omega))+cos(GHA) * sin(omega) * sin(t))/(cos(d) * cos(GHA) * cos(omega)+sin(omega)*  (cos(GHA) * cos(t) * sin(d)+sin(GHA)* sin(t)))) + (cos(d)* cos(GHA)* cos(omega) +  sin(omega) * (cos(GHA)* cos(t) * sin(d) + sin(GHA)  *sin(t)) >0.0 ? 0.0 : pi)) , lambda - 2.0*pi*floor(lambda/(2.0*pi)))

lambda_min = 170
lambda_max = 190
phi_min    = 310
phi_max    = 80

set xrange [xe(lambda_min):xe(lambda_max)]
set yrange [ye(phi_min)   :ye(phi_max)]
set parametric

plot [t=0   :2.09] '+' u (xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))):(ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))) w l lc rgb "red"  ti "A" ,\
     [t=2.09:2*pi] '+' u (xe(K*LAMBDA(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))):(ye(K*PHI(t, 0.46, 4.63, 1.25))) w l lc rgb "blue" ti "B"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]